# convert server time to user device time in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, momentjs, phonegap

okay, so i want to show the server time converted to the user device timezone

im saving the date in firebase database using:

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

im using moment.js to convert it to the user device im using this code

```
timezone="Europe/London"; //get device time zone with corddova  later

var date   = moment.tz(snapshot3.val().date, timezone).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");
```

as you see this need the timezone name of the device to do so, how can i get it using cordova/Phonegap ?

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved this, i abandoned geting device time zone name, i just used moment.js function

```
    var timezone = moment.tz.guess(); //get device time zone
```